# EXCEL ADODB Query on local worksheet not Including newly inserted records

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I am using ADODB to query data form a worksheet in the Active workbook.  The data resides on it's own sheet, and has column headers.  I've defined the table as an excel ListObject - excel's automatic table formatting construct.

I open the connection like this:

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & _ 
   ThisWorkbook.Name & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
cn.Open strCon
```

Then I can fetch a recordset using a simple SQL statement:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * from [sheet1$]
rs.Open strSQL, cn, 0, 1  'cursortype = adOpenForwardOnly, locktype = adOpenReadonly
```

This all works fine... until I insert a new row in the table on sheet1.  The new row is not included in subsequent queries, even if I close, set to nothing, and re-open both the connection and recordset variables in my code.

If I save and close the workbook, and then re-open it, the new records ARE included in the query, which leads me to believe this might be a caching issue.  I've searched for ADODB Cache Flush etc, but most results appear to be related to PHP or Access.  I've also tried a variety of other options for Cursor Type and Lock Type, with no difference.

Can anyone suggest how I can ensure that each time I run my query I get all the rows, even after I insert new rows in the table?

Comment: I just tested some more, and found that even if I edit a single value in the table, the edit doesn't come through in the query - it still brings back the old value.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution:

Since I'm using Excel 2010, I discovered that I can use a newer version of ADODB.

So, instead of defining my connection string like this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="...
```

I changed it to this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="...
```

and the problem is solved.  New inserts and edits are now showing up immediately after I make them.  This also removes the issue of the known memory leak in OLEDB.4.0, so that's a bonus.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just ran into the same problem with newly created worksheets in an unsaved file not being visible to ADODB, and using the ACE provider resolved that.