# Cannot update the fields using ADODB from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, field, adodb

My goal is to be able to read and write the cell values from a closed workbook. I use ADODB to get the needed information.
A file is generated by a corporate website, so I can't change the contents before using the actual file. The file is in Excel format. No formulas in cells present, just values.
I would like to get dates, strings, integers from a worksheet, but I met some restrictions.

I wrote the sample code to show you what happens:

```
Dim rsConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFieldNames As String
Dim intValue As Integer

strFileName = "C:\Tests\Sample.xlsx" ' Fullpath to a workbook
'strFieldNames = "CInt([Proj_Year]) as [Proj_Year]"
'strFieldNames = "[Proj_Year]"
strFieldNames = "*"

Set rsConn = New ADODB.Connection
With rsConn
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strFileName & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR=YES; "";"
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open
End With

Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset
With rsData
    .Source = "SELECT " & strFieldNames & " FROM A2:AE500;" ' Sheetname not required
    .ActiveConnection = rsConn
    '.CursorType = adOpenKeyset     ' Tried this - didn't work
    '.CursorType = adOpenDynamic     ' Tried this - didn't work
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open
End With

With rsData
    .MoveFirst
    Do While Not .EOF
        ' Getting the value
        intValue = .Fields(0).Value

        ' Make some crazy modifications of the value
        intValue = intValue + 10

        ' Updating
        .Fields(0).Value = intValue   ' this is place where crash happens

        ' Move to the next record
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

rsData.Close
Set rsData = Nothing
rsConn.Close
Set rsConn = Nothing
```

Here is a screenshot of the sample workbook:

[image: screenshot]

I tried several approaches:

1. `strFieldNames = "*"`
   I get all columns present in the worksheet. But the driver tries to guess the field types and I don't like it because its guessing are wrong. For example, cell I3 should be string but in reality it is `adDouble`. So the reading might be ok but I can't write back as a string.
   I tried using `IMEX=1` but it didn't help, tried `MAXSCANROWS=1`, `Readonly=0` but also have no luck. I don't want to touch windows registry to modify guessing rows.
2. `strFieldNames = "[Proj_Year]"`
   I receive only one column but I met same restrictions as in 1.
3. `strFieldNames = "CInt([Proj_Year]) as [Proj_Year]"`
   I receive the required columns in type I want. But when I ran the code I receive:

*Field cannot be updated*

in code: `.Fields(0).Value = intValue`

In the code above I read and write by one record at a time. I tried to read all data (30 columns, 3000 rows) by using GetRows and then parse the array of data into my own class. After all data is read then I modify this data and write it back to the worksheet one record at a time.

What do I need to do in order to get this code working?

Comment: `SELECT " & strFieldNames & " FROM A2:AE500;`?  Shouldn't it be something like `strSQL = "SELECT * from [sheet1$]`(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193112/excel-adodb-query-on-local-worksheet-not-including-newly-inserted-records)? After the `From` should be the sheet name and not the range (on any given sheet) even if you have only one sheet in your file. Also, the sheet name should be followed by a `$` and encapsulated in square brackets. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/278973/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-workbooks

Comment: By adding a worksheet name doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I suspect that the ACE driver has issues with recordset changes in Excel with a static cursor.  You might want to try `adOpenKeyset`. Personally, I'd use a second command object to issue `UPDATE` requests.

Comment: If I use `adOpenKeyset` and `strFieldNames = "CInt([Proj_Year]) as [Proj_Year]"` the program will behave as before. What about `UPDATE`? Can you give me some examples?

Comment: You need adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

Comment: I tried this before, didn't help. Added to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I typically just use the `Execute` method of the `Connection` object.

My **Before** data set (this is the data in the file located at the `FilePath` variable):

```
Field1  Field2
   1    a
   2    b
   3    c
   4    d
   5    e
```

My **After** data set:

```
Field1  Field2
   1    b
   2    b
   3    c
   4    d
   5    e
```

Here's the code that's working for me.

```
Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\MyComputerName\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"
Const ConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & _
                          ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"

Public Sub testUpdate()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection: Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

    With conn
        .connectionstring = ConnStr
        .Open
        .Execute "Update [Sheet1$] set Field2='b' where Field1=1"
    End With

    If conn.State = adopenstate Then conn.Close: Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

### **A few other observations**

- This `strFileName = "C:\Tests\Sample.xlxs"` doesn't appear to be a valid file name. So this might be giving you grief.
- The first row of the data set doesn't contain headers, so using the sheet name `[Sheet1$]` for example I believe defaults to `F1,F2,F3` representing the field names (F1 = Field1). If you want the best of both worlds, qualify the range with the Sheet *AND* Range like this: `[Sheet1$A1:B10]`. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/278973/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-workbooks) more details.

Comment: Then I would like to know more examples about: `.Execute "Update [Sheet1$] set Field2='b' where Field1=1"`.

Comment: What if I want to modify the following cells: B6="Open", C12=123, E9=345, I17=Null, etc. What if I have 300 rows to modify. How about that?  About observations. I wrote a fake filename, because it's just an example.  I don't know why you are saying about first row, when I use the 2nd row as row with headers. And sheetname is not required, I was asked the same question above.

Comment: Xlxs isn't a valid file extension is my point, mentioning that in case that's a problem. You are writing a SQL statement that updates records, not updating cells in a range object. You'd update the record you want, typically by specifying a condition in the where clause. Check out the ADO documentation for more info on SO.

Comment: As far as I can see it's not possible to update all the fields in all the records by using `.Execute "Update ..."`

Comment: Sure it is. Just don't specify any condition in the where clause. It will update all records if all apply.

Comment: I couldn't find any examples that may fit my needs.